# Is there any way to reach my friends' photos in Facebook using the API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to reach my friend's photo in an application. I gave all permissions to this application but Facebook needs friend's permission for access to photos.

So is there anyway to fix this? Can I take a special permission from Facebook?

Comment: No. You friends needs to login to your app and give permission for the app to access their photots

Comment: thanks for your help, I want to ask another thing, what is taggable friends photo and can I use taggable friends photos in my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, your friends need to login to your application and grant the necessary permissions to access their photos.

So, no, there is no way to do it with a special permission.